# How to apply a diff that consists of + and - lines, with no other headers etc

Tags: unix

I have a diff file that consists of lines like the following:

```
-a line to remove
+a line to add
```

There are no headers etc so it appears incompatible with unix patch. Is there another way to apply this?

Comment: It don't have line numbers? I'm not even sure how it meant to be applied, logically. Maybe it is provided just as pseudocode example?

Comment: It just means remove all lines with the - and add lines with the +. You're right in that it's not really context aware.

Comment: If you have only one of these things, it would be easier to just run `sed -i 's/line_to_remove/line_to_add/g' your_file` (make backup first) (be aware of potential special regex characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$ diff -u oldFile newFile > mods.diff
$ patch < mods.diff
```

The first one to create the patch and the second to apply it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have oldFile and newFile - I just have oldFile and a quasi-patch file that consists only of + and - lines.

Comment: I think you have no way to make a patch with only theses information. But you can make your own script with grep, sed, etc.